# How to use layout to arrange complex plots in one page in r

Tags: r

I am trying to use `layout()` to create a pdf with four plots on one page. I created the matrix and give the order of the plots with this line

```
layout(mat=matrix(c(1,2,3,4), nrow = 4, ncol = 1))
```

After that, I try to load one of the saved plots in the layout but that does not seem to work. It just loads the plot by itself.

So I tried copying the code of the plot after the layout but I am getting multiple errors starting by a margin Error.

```
    par(mar=c(4, 6, 4, 6) + 0.1,cex.axis=0.8)#START A NEW PLOT FRAME

plot(acms_day$end,acms_day$Org,pty='s',xaxt='n',#CALL THE DESIRED VARIABLES
     type = 'b',lty=2,lwd=0.01,
     xlim=period,ylim=c(0,max(acms_day$Org,na.rm = T)),#SET LIMITS OF X AND Y AXIS
     xlab='', ylab='',
     bg=color_pal[14],
     col=color_pal[14],
     axes=F, main='',
     cex=0.5,las=1,pch=21)
axis(2, ylim=c(0,max(acms_day$Org,na.rm = T)),
     col='black',lwd=0.2,cex = 0.8,las=1)
mtext(2,text='Org (ug/m3)',line=2.2,
      col=color_pal[14],cex = 0.8,las=0) 
par(new=T) #START A NEW PLOT OVER THE DAME FRAME
plot(maap_day$date,maap_day$bc,pty='s',xaxt='n',#CALL THE DESIRED VARIABLES
     type = 'p',#lty=2,lwd=0.01,
     xlim=period,ylim=c(0,max(maap_day$bc,na.rm = T)),#SET LIMITS OF X AND Y AXIS
     xlab='', ylab='',
     col=color_pal[3], pch=21,
     bg=color_pal[3], 
     main='',cex=0.5,yaxt='n',ann = FALSE,xaxt='n')
axis(4, ylim=c(0,max(maap_day$bc,na.rm = T)),
     col='black',lwd=0.2,cex = 0.8,las=1)
mtext(4,text='BC (ug/m3)',line=2.2,
      col=color_pal[3],cex = 0.8,las=0)

axis.POSIXct(1,acsm_long$end,at = hours,format = '%H:%M')
rug(hours, ticksize = -0.01, side = 1)#create minor breaks
rug(days,ticksize = -0.02,side=1) #create day breaks
```

As soon as the first line runs this Error appears Error in plot.new() : figure margins too large.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you're using RStudio, make sure your "Files, Plots, Packages, Help, View" pane is large enough (1/4 of the screen should do).

Comment: Thanks. indeed this was the issue. Do you know if there is a way to control the size of the plot before showing it on the screen?

Comment: Yes - adjust the "Files, Plots, Packages, Help, View" pane as I said. Other than that, then you can use the `windows()` function (for Windows OS) and `X11()` (for unix look-alikes). And look at `Devices` for sending to files.